# Jhipster deploy only frontend ( existing project )

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm using **Jhipster** for my web application, Spring Boot and angular.

I want to work with **frontend freelance developer**, For that I would like to deploy the frontend separately.

How can I do it?

Comment: What is "frontend freelance developer"? To deploy the frontend separately, you don't necessarily need to isolate it in its own folder/repo, it can be easily done by the build process. Please  edit your question to clarify it. Why did you tag it with jhipster-registry?

Answer (score 1):

Like [Gaël Marziou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93960/ga%C3%ABl-marziou) mentioned, it isn't necessary to separate the frontend code from the backend code. Your app is generated with angular: you'll find the frontend code in `src/main/webapp` and you can edit the Angular-code of your jhipster generated application with any development tool.

You also can generate the frontend only with `jhipster --skip-server` as mentioned in https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/.